# How to use ngb-accordion in a ngFor loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, accordion, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the [ngb-accordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) in a for loop. It's working for a part, but it seems that it is not possible to open the active element in a for loop.

I want make it possible that when one of the accordion elements includes the property `'OpenAccordion'` the panel of that element opens. So I need to define the `activeIds` and the `id` for each element inside the array to make it possible.

When I define the *ngFor outside the `<ngb-accordion></ngb-accordion>` it works because I can link the index to the `activeIds` and `id`. But his time it's not possible to open one panel at a time because the panels are seperate.

`[closeOthers]` is working on this one but `open one panel at a time` is not working:

```
<ngb-accordion  
    class="accordion-item" 
    [closeOthers]="true"  
    activeIds="true-{{i}}">

    <div *ngFor="let child of items?.children | async; let i = index">
        <ngb-panel id="{{(child?.value?.properties | async)?.property.includes('OpenAccordion')}}-{{i}}">
            <ng-template ngbPanelHeader let-opened="opened">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <button ngbPanelToggle class="btn btn-link container-fluid text-left">
                        <h5>
                            {{ (child?.value?.properties | async)?.title }}
                        </h5>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                <h4>test</h4>
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
    </div>

</ngb-accordion>
```

When I define the *ngFor inside the `<ngb-accordion></ngb-accordion>` the `[closeOthers]` functionality works, but this time it's not possible to open the active accordion panel. Because the index of the activeId is unknown and does not match the id of the active element.

`Open one panel at a time` is working but `[closeOthers]` is not working on this one:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-child [ngForOf]="items?.children | async" let-i="index">
    <ngb-accordion  
        class="accordion-item" 
        [closeOthers]="true"  
        activeIds="true-{{i}}">

        <ngb-panel id="{{(child?.value?.properties | async)?.property.includes('OpenAccordion')}}-{{i}}">
            <ng-template ngbPanelHeader let-opened="opened">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <button ngbPanelToggle class="btn btn-link container-fluid text-left">
                        <h5>
                            {{ (child?.value?.properties | async)?.title }}
                        </h5>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                <h4>test</h4>
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
    </ngb-accordion>
</ng-template>
```

How can I make it possible to let both functions `[closeOthers]` and `open one panel at a time` works in a *ngFor loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you first solution, there is a mistake, you used the variable **i** before it is declared:

```
<ngb-accordion  
class="accordion-item" 
[closeOthers]="true"  
activeIds="true-{{i}}"> // i used before declaration?

<div *ngFor="let child of items?.children | async; let i = index">
```

I just created a simple sample to use ngFor with ngb-accordion, it works good.

You should try to ngFor inside the `<ngb-accordion>`:

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-accordion-static',
  templateUrl: './accordion-static.html'
})
export class NgbdAccordionStatic {

  accordionSamples = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Simple',
      content: `Simple content sample`
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Fancy',
      content: `Fancy content interesting`
    }
    ]

}
```

HTML:

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="acc-2">
  <ngb-panel *ngFor="let acc of accordionSamples" id="acc-{{acc.id}}" title="{{acc.title}}">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      {{acc.content}}
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdbedd?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion-static.html

Comment: yes I defined before the declaration but, I need to set the `activeId` dynamically because I want to set the active accordion when the property `OpenAccordion` is available in the object.

Your answer is right when the activeId is static like `acc-2`. But I want to set the activeId dynamically.

Comment: You used `i` before declaration. Please see my updated stackblitz, the activeId is dynamic, and you can click the toggle button to change it. Please view it carefully, and see if you still has any question.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdbedd

Comment: Got it working now but the unit test fails when I use the AsyncPipe. `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`